# Unable to use multiple mail servers dynamically at runtime. Using spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, mail-server

### I have this factory from where a mailServiceImpl gets picked depending on some inputs:

```
public class EmailFactory {
    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public EmailService getMailService(String mailServerName){
        switch (mailServerName){
            case "gmail":
                logger.info("Gmail setup as mail service!");
                return beanFactory.getBean("gmailMailServiceImpl", EmailService.class);
            case "zoho":
                logger.info("Zoho setup as mail service!");
                return beanFactory.getBean("zohoMailServiceImpl", EmailService.class);
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("mailServerName not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Each mailServiceImpl bean has their own properties: like mail.hostname, mail.username etc. And they are used to send mail.

The problem is that at startup the zoho configuration i.e., zohoMailServiceImpl is set as default somehow and I'm unable to send messages using gmail server.
When I try sending using gmail configurated bean, its showing Relay Exception.

### I want to use both the mail servers without relays. Is it possible or not? And how much will it affect performance to have both of them? Please help.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Failed to close server connection after message failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as myUserName@localhost

Comment: You are using Gmail as a relay server. And the exception tells you, that it is not allowed for the mail adress, which you specified as sender address. AFAIK, if you want to use the Gmail servers, you have to specify the email adress from the account, which you use for authentication, as sender adress.

Comment: @dunni Hi, thanks for the reply. I know that it can be done by adding the sender address in my account, but I want to have a mail server that doesn't use gmail server if I want to use another server and vice versa. And that is w/o adding the sender address to the other account.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. The solution turns out to be pretty simple. I removed the properties files from where the configurations were picked and populated the configurations in the Java configuration files instead.